# Failed to load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in angular js 1 visual studio 2013

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-functions

this is murugan. I'm a newbie to firebase cloud functions, So what i did wrote a FCF to send a email notification to whom i want send with node mailer

```
mailOptions  ={
        from: '"my test app" <murugansakthivel.pk@gmail.com>',
        to:emails,
        subject:"My First cloud functions",
        text:emailText,
    };
```

then i deployed it in the firebase and it successfully deployed it. Following then i used the url to from my angular js code like below,

```
var url = 'https://us-central1-myappname.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail';
var config = {
          data : {
                   employees: answer.selectedEmployees,
                   title: cnt.Title
                },
              headers:{
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                      }
           }

$http.post(url, data, header).then(function (success) {
           result = result + ' &' + success;
          _callSuccessCntMessage(action, result);
        });
```

I'm writing this code in visual studio 2013. when i invoked this function then got a error saying

"**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9137' is therefore not allowed access.** "

Then i googled about it, following i got suggestion saying add below code in the FCF

```
const express=require('express');
const cors= require('cors')({origin:true});
const app=express();
app.use(cors);

request.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
request.header('Content-Type','application/json');    
request.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
```

added it in code then deployed the cloud functions. The error remains the same.

I'm still not able find a solution for this. Please don't mark this as duplicate my situation is completely different from others issue.

I'm desperately needing help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` in windows for it

Comment: where to add this.

Comment: run the above command in cmd and it will open chrome with disabled security and then you can run your project to test

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Step 1 - Press `windows + r`. Step 2 - Paste the above code and enter.
It will open a new chrome session and now hit your 'http://localhost:9137' there

Comment: yeah it's working. i m gng to implement this in realtime project how do i tell my user to disable chrome security in order to use this feature.?

Comment: please donot use this in production server. For this you have to buy SSL certificate

Comment: Ok thank you. will look into that

Answer (score 0):

You can set config allow-origin in web.config file of `localhost:9137` project:

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

With this config you have permission to this port, also you can customize it by add custom port to it:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:1506, http://localhost:1502" />
```

With this config just ports `1506` and `1502` has allow to get from port `9137`

Comment: where to add this code ? <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:1506, http://localhost:1502" />

Comment: put it in file on your directory `web.config`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following steps for testing it in local environment :

**Step 1 -  Press windows + r 

Step 2 - Copy `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security` there.

Step 3  - run your localhost in the chrome opened.**

But this is for local development only. For Production you have to use SSL certificates.